# Understanding delegate and scoped methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates

In active_record/base.rb, `module ActiveRecord` you can see this code:

```
delegate :find, :first, :last, :all, :destroy, :destroy_all, :exists?, :delete, 
             :delete_all, :update, :update_all, :to => :scoped
```

Let's take `first` method, so i assumed that `first` method delegates to `scoped` method and then `scoped` should return the first record from database. But `scoped` is just the anonymous `scope`, how the current construction is doing its job?

At the same time, how dynamic methods work, like `find_by_name`, `find_all_by_name_and_colour`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate), `delegate`:

> Provides a delegate class method to
>   easily expose contained objects’
>   methods as your own. Pass one or more
>   methods (specified as symbols or
>   strings) and the name of the target
>   object via the :to option (also a
>   symbol or string)

So this delegates the methods in the list to the `scoped` method, which is defined in ActiveRecord::NamedScoped::ClassMethods, and which [returns an anonymous scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped).

As to why ActiveRecord does this, it is so we can continue to use familiar methods such as `find` while behind the scenes AR is actually calling the fancy new Arel methods. For instance, when you do

```
Post.find(37)
```

What actually gets executed is:

```
Post.where(primary_key.eq(37))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer to your second question. find_by_name and find_all_by_what_you_want rely on ruby's precious method_missing. Whenever a method doesn't exist, the object calls method_missing, which you can overwrite. For example, I may want to overwrite method_missing, catch all non-existing method calls, check with some regex if they start/end/contain some keywords, etc.

In your example, I'll overwrite method_missing, check if it starts by find, and if yes, split on the '*and*' keyword to get an array of they attributes with which I want to do my find.

Here is a pretty good example : http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/

Answer (score 1):

First:  "delegate" delegates to an object, not a method - so "scope" must be some object.

Without inspecting the source to verify and just going on my working knowledge of ActiveRecord, I'm going to assume that "scope" will be the current AR instance, unless it's being called on an association proxy.

Therefore:

```
User.first # "scope" will be User

User.posts.first # "scope" will be the Post collection proxy
```

@christianblais is correct on question #2, `method_missing` is handling these calls.  Furthermore, Rails actually defines the missing method on first call, so that subsequent calls to it do not incur the overhead of `method_missing`